# Invoke-VMScript to call another ps1 file to install setup.exe inside iso

Tags: powershell

I am executing the below code where i am calling a .ps1 file which is having code to execute setup.exe inside mounted iso file in z: drive

```
Invoke-VMScript -VM "999_OSTest_Clone" -ScriptText c:\SB\isoscript.ps1 -GuestUser Administrator -GuestPassword Pa -ScriptType Powershell
```

**isoscript.ps1**

```
# Define the drive letter of the CD/DVD drive
$driveLetter = "Z:"
# Construct the command to start the installation
$command = "$driveLetter\setup.exe"
# Start the installation process
Start-Process -FilePath $command -ArgumentList "/quiet /noreboot" -Wait -passThru
```

the script executed without any error but provided this below output. I am not able to see anything in the cloned VM and also the output of the command also I am not able to understand

```
ScriptOutput
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|  
|  Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                  
|  -------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                  
|       51       8     1560       5284       0,00    876   0 setup                                                        
|  
|  
|  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me understand what is going on here and is the code able to execute setup.exe or not

**Update**

Updated command from
`Start-Process -FilePath $command -ArgumentList "/quiet /noreboot" -Wait -passThru`
to
`& $command "/quiet /noreboot"`

but getting this window in powershell ISE and it is not moving at all

[image]

Comment: Change `Start-Process -FilePath $command -ArgumentList "/quiet /noreboot" -Wait -passThru` to just `& $command "/quiet /noreboot"` then

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I changed the command, but after execution it seems it went to a hang mode. not able to see any progress. not sure what is happening in background. there is a powershell process I am able to see in the clone VM but nothing else